# Give priority to child theme stylesheet

Tags: child-theme, wp-enqueue-style, css

I've created a child theme and the main style.css works perfectly fine. However, the parent theme has another stylesheet which I want to import and create the same for child theme and use it instead.

> Parent theme structure - ./woocommerce/woo.css 
>   Child theme structure - ./woocommerce/woo.css (Manually created)

Now, I enqueued both the stylesheets in the child theme's function.php as below.

```
function fruitful_load_parent_stylesheets() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'layout', get_template_directory_uri() . '/woocommerce/woo.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'fruitful_load_parent_stylesheets' );

function fruitful_load_child_stylesheets(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'woo', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/woocommerce/woo.css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'fruitful_load_child_stylesheets');
```

Now, if I add a style to the child theme's woo.css, it doesn't work until I **!important** it.I just don't want to go doing it on every style I add.

is

Comment: Please have a look at [this comment](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/211723/child-theme-functions-php-issues/211727#comment307540_211727)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your child theme's `stylesheet`  will usually be loaded automatically. If it is not, you will need to `enqueue` it as well. Setting 'parent-style' as a dependency will ensure that the child theme `stylesheet` loads after it.

```
/**
 * Enqueue theme styles (parent first, child second)
 * 
 */
function wpse218610_theme_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'parent-style';

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/woocommerce/woo.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/woocommerce/woo.css', array( $parent_style ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse218610_theme_styles' );
```

> Note: take a look in the [Theme Developer Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/#3-enqueue-stylesheet) for some extra information.

Comment: This worked after I commented out the enqueue of woo.css in the parent theme's functions.php. I'll accept this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps you can try adding a priority value to each add_action to make sure that one executes before the other.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'fruitful_load_parent_stylesheets', 10 );
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'fruitful_load_child_stylesheets', 20 );
```

[WordPress Codex add_action()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/)

Comment: Didn't work. Here's the link to the screenshot of inspect element - http://i.imgur.com/Mb34NJa.png

The third block is from the child theme's woo.css while the first two are from the parent theme's. I don't know why they're being loaded twice.

Comment: Setting the priority worked for me. I had to set it higher than 10 for it to "overtake" the parent theme's enqueue.

Comment: for me too - I can now override settings of my parent theme (purchased template)

Answer (score 3):

I got to load child theme later like below. I had to dequeue & deregister parent style, then enqueue parent style & child style. Hope this helps

Parent `functions.php` has

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_parent_style', 10);
function load_parent_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style('parent-theme-style'); // parent theme code
}
```

Child `functions.php` has

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_child_style', 20);
function load_child_style() {
  //register & enqueue parent with new name 
  wp_register_style('parent-style', $url, array($deps));
  wp_enqueue_style('parent-style'); 

  // dequeue & deregister parent's theme handle
  wp_dequeue_style('parent-theme-style'); // from parent theme
  wp_deregister_style('parent-theme-style'); 

  // register & enqueue child style
  wp_register_style('child-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array('parent-style'));
  wp_enqueue_style('child-style');
}
```